Delete object from RoomDB from an action in notification, while the app is closed
So I was creating a Tasks Application, where user can add and delete tasks, I have given this option to remind the task after 4 hour through a notification. The notification has a 'Done' action which should delete the task from the RoomDB, but I can't figure out how to do so.
I am very new to Android dev, don't know much.
I tried using a thread inside Broadcast Receiver which runs the Dao delete task function but it doesn't work while the app is closed (not even present in recent apps)
Using WorkManager:
This is my BroadcastReceiver which handles the action from notification
class TaskDone: BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        val text: String? = intent.getStringExtra("text")
        val notificationId: Int = intent.getIntExtra("notificationId", 1)
        val notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager
        notificationManager.cancel(notificationId)
        val workerRequest = OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(DeleteTask::class.java)
            .setInputData(
                Data.Builder()
                    .putString("text", text)
                    .build()
            )
            .build()
        WorkManager.getInstance(context).enqueue(workerRequest)
        Toast.makeText(context, "Done: $text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}

This is my Worker Class
class DeleteTask(context: Context, workerParams: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, workerParams) {
override fun doWork(): Result {
    TaskDatabase.createDatabase(applicationContext)  //edit
    val taskDao = TaskDatabase.getDatabase().getTaskDao()
    val text = inputData.getString("text")
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        taskDao.deleteTaskByText(text!!)
    }
    return Result.success()
}

}
But this still doesn't solve the issue. It does work while the app is open or is in recent apps section but not while the app is completely closed(removed from recents too)
Edit: i forgot to create an instance of the db before accessing the dao. after i did, it works. the above code now works fine.

You can use WorkManager for this task
Schedule a One Time Work task to do this and be ensured that this will be done and compatibility is ensured across a lot of Android version
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager

I'm currently using AlarmManager for the notification, do i need to change that too or can i schedule the work from the action itself. Sorry if this a silly question.

You can use the AlarmManager as well, but WorkManager does things more consistently. There are subtle differences as well, which you can see in detail here

tried using OneTimeWorkRequest but still didn't work. you can check the latest edit for the code.

thanks, it did work. i forgot to create an instance of the db while inside of the worker class. it works after creating an instance.

You won't need a CoroutineScope. You can use CoroutineWorker
